# Resolving Compilation Failure of Rcpp-Based R Package on CRAN Linux VMs Due to Makevars Issues

Tags: r, package, rcpp, cran, rcpparmadillo

I'm currently developing an R package named `nonprobsvy` and facing difficulties getting it to compile on CRAN's Linux virtual machines (e.g., Debian). The package uses `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`, and while it installs without issues on my MacBook Air (M1 processor, macOS Sonoma 14.0), it fails on CRAN's Linux environments. I suspect the problem lies with my `Makevars` configuration, but I'm not sure how to adjust it for compatibility.

Here is the content of my `Makevars` file for now:

```
## Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
#PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

When uncomment second line then compilation does not work on my local machine. The error then is

```
 ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
   ld: library 'gfortran' not found
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   make: *** [nonprobsvy.so] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nonprobsvy’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/yh/41pvj0v54_jfq6w138_b1z740000gn/T/RtmpyINTst/devtools_install_3b69498b0fdf/nonprobsvy’
```

And here is a screenshot of the error message generated on the CRAN Linux machines:
[CRAN error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knh2l.png)

I tried to add a configure file with the flag indicating whether the package is compiled on my local machine or not, like this

```
#!/bin/sh

# Sprawdź zmienną środowiskową
if [ "$USE_LOCAL_SETTINGS" = "1" ]; then
    # Generuj Makevars dla lokalnego użytku
    echo "PKG_LIBS = " > src/Makevars
else
    # Generuj Makevars dla normalnego użytku
    echo "PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)" > src/Makevars
fi
```

The package installed locally however there was still a problem on CRAN machines. By the way to check for CRAN submission I used rhub package.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to modify my Makevars to ensure compatibility across platforms, especially to address any potential issues with the Linux environment on CRAN's VMs. Has anyone encountered similar issues with Rcpp or RcppArmadillo in their packages? Any insights or suggestions would be immensely helpful.

Comment: If you use `RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("mypkg")` you should find yourself with a working package with correct `Makevars` and `Makevars.win`.  What you show above has AFAIK not been needed for a decade as `Rcpp` stopped requiring linking then.  You also seem confused about your VM (that you talk about) and where you actually run your build which seems to under macOS and _clearly shows that you lack the Fortran compiler `gfortran` which is needed for `RcppArmadillo`_  because the use of LAPACK and BLAS implies use of Fortan _libraries_.

Comment: Also the line you quote from your `Makevars` is _commented-out_.  Try using `PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)` which is what the skeleton gives you.

Comment: @AdaLovelace You are right, except that I have a Fortran compiler on my local computer. However, the problem may be because it is in a different file path than RcppArmadillo requires. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes macOS setups for R require extra care, this is documented in a few places.  Try https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/